# Get data inside html tags using Simple HTML DOM Parser:

Tags: php, html-table, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to get all the information inside the html tags and display them in a table. I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser. I tried the following code but I'm only getting the LAST COLUMN (Column:Total). How do I get the data from the other columns?

```
foreach($html->find('tr[class="tblRowShade"]') as $div) {
    $key = '';
    $val = '';

    foreach($div->find('*') as $node) {
        if ($node->tag=='td'){
            $key = $node->plaintext;
        }
    }

    $ret[$key] = $val;
}
```

Here's my code for the table

```
 <tr class="tblRowShade">
      <td width="12%"><strong>Project</strong></td>
      <td width="38%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%"><strong>Recipient</strong></td>
      <td width="14%"><strong>Municipality/City</strong></td>
      <td width="11%" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right"><strong>Implementing Unit</strong></td>
      <td width="11%" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right"><strong>Release Date</strong></td>
      <td align="right" width="11%" class="td_right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
 </tr>

<tr class="tblRowShade">
      <td colspan="2" >Livelihood Programs</td>
      <td >Basic Espresso and Latte</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
      <td >DOLE - TESDA Regional Office IV-A</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap">2013-06-11</td>
      <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right">1,500,000</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `$div->find('*')`? you can try `$div->find('td')` instead.  This should produce correct result.  Otherwise you can also try to iterate over children: `foreach($div->children as $node)`

Assuming you are trying to use the first row as $key and the rest for the data, you might want to alter your HTML code by simply add `th` in the first row, which is your header: `<tr><th>…</th></tr>`.  This way you can get the keys by `$div->find('th')`.  I suppose using the first row is okay as well.

Answer (score 0):

As alamin.ahmed said, it would be better to search for `td` instead...

Here's a working example :

```
$text = ' <tr class="tblRowShade">
      <td width="12%"><strong>Project</strong></td>
      <td width="38%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%"><strong>Recipient</strong></td>
      <td width="14%"><strong>Municipality/City</strong></td>
      <td width="11%" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right"><strong>Implementing Unit</strong></td>
      <td width="11%" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right"><strong>Release Date</strong></td>
      <td align="right" width="11%" class="td_right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
 </tr>

<tr class="tblRowShade">
      <td colspan="2" >Livelihood Programs</td>
      <td >Basic Espresso and Latte</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
      <td >DOLE - TESDA Regional Office IV-A</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap">2013-06-11</td>
      <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="td_right">1,500,000</td>
</tr>';

echo  "<div>Original Text: <xmp>$text</xmp></div>";


//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($text);


// Find all elements
$rows = $html->find('tr[class="tblRowShade"]');


// Find succeeded
if ($rows) {

    echo count($rows) . " \$rows found !<br />";

    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {

        echo "<hr />";

        $columns = $row->find('td');

        // Find succeeded
        if ($rows) {

            echo count($columns) . " \$columns found  in \$rows[$key]!<br />";

            foreach ($columns as $col) {

                    echo $col->plaintext . " | ";
                }
        }
        else
            echo " /!\ Find() \$columns failed /!\ ";
    }
}
else
    echo " /!\ Find() \$rows failed /!\ ";
```

here's the output of the above code:

[image]

You must be aware that the two rows doesnt contain the same number of columns... then you must handle that in your program.